# Initializing derived classes in the same way

Tags: c++, unit-testing, inheritance, initialization

I have a class Base that has several children, say A, B, C. For testing purposes I'd like to mock those derived classes by deriving from them. So MockA derives from A, MockB derives from B and so on.

The problem is, that MockA, MockB, ... all inherit protected members from Base that have to be set in the same way in each mock class. The code looks like this:

```
MockA::init()
{
    x = 1;     // inherited from Base
    y = "abc"; // inherited from Base
    z = 0.5;   // inherited from Base
}

MockB::init()
{
    x = 1;     // inherited from Base
    y = "abc"; // inherited from Base
    z = 0.5;   // inherited from Base
}
```

and so on.

So my question is, how can I avoid this cut&paste initialization? Can I achieve it without touching Base, A, B, C, ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a "mixin". In C++ they are usually implemented with templates and specifically using CRTP, the ["curiously recurring template pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). It might be an overkill if it's just a bit of common code, than Pierre's answer seems most appropriate. But as the amount of common code for the mock classes grows, so will value of template.

Basic CRTP would go like this:

```
template <typename ConcreteT> class Mock {
    initMock() {
        static_cast<ConcreteT *>(this)->x = 1;
        static_cast<ConcreteT *>(this)->y = "abc";
        static_cast<ConcreteT *>(this)->z = 0.5;
    }
};

class MockA : A, Mock<MockA> { ... };
//                    ^^^^^ specialized on the type that inherits it, that's the point
```

Here it would make things simple to inherit A *through* the Mock class though, so

```
template <typename BaseT> class Mock : public BaseT {
    initMock() {
        x = 1;
        y = "abc";
        z = 0.5;
    }
};

class MockA : Mock<A> { ... };
//                 ^ just the base class
```

That does away with the ugly static_casts, but does not allow you to provide methods in `MockA` that will be called by `Mock`. But you can have both...

```
template<typename ConcreteT, typename BaseT>
class Mock : public BaseT { ... };

class MockA : Mock<MockA, A> { ... };
```

Now `Mock` can call methods of `MockA` on itself via static cast and call methods of `A` (or rather the ultimate base) directly.

---

Note: The mixin templates are basically the same thing as mixins in Ruby or interfaces with method implementations introduced in Java 8. Those languages it is a special construct, because they don't have anything of the power of C++ templates, but the implementation is similar—an intermediate class is constructed by compiler and injected in the hierarchy.

Comment: Uh, I hope I understand that correctly. So if I want MockA to be derived from A, I have to go for the first version, right?

Comment: No wait, Base is a template parameter, not the actual Base class. Aha, so by inheriting from Mock<A> MockA DOES inherit from A.

Comment: Pierre's answer simply does not work, see my comment below. If my answer is not applicable (because A,B,C and their base class cannot be changed, not even a line, under no circumstances), then I guess your solution is the best option. Thus +1.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi: I've suffixed all template parameter names with `T` to disambiguate them. Yes, by inheriting `Mock<A>` you are indirectly inheriting `A`, only single inheritance involved.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could introduce a static method which returns a default set of all protected member values and fetch them in each init method into the fields of the mock objects.

Edit:

```
MockA::init()
{
  initMock(MockInitializer.getDefaultValues());
  //go on with your code
}

MockA::initMock(anystruct def_values)
{
  //assign your values
}
```

The problem is that in any place you'll have to do the assignment, why not do it in its own method?

Comment: This default set is a struct / data class? Well, yes, at least the data is then the same for all mock classes. But still the "fetch into the fields" part will always look alike in every mock class. I would rather prefer a solution where the initialization shrinks down to one line.

Comment: So initMock() will be the same in MockA, MockB, MockC?

Comment: yes it will at least when the assigned variables are the same!

Comment: @Pierre Fourgeaud what if the default values differ for MockA and MockB?

Comment: At the moment I have something similar in fact. But I'm not satisfied with this because the code repetition is, in fact, still there. It's just different lines that are repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i would to that if I understand your problem :

```
class Base
{
protected:
    initMock()
    {
        x = 1;
        y = "abc";
        z = 0.5;
    }
};

class A { /* Whatever you want ... */ };

class B { /* Whatever you want ... */ };

class MockA : public A, public Base
{
public:
    initMock()
    {
         Base::initMock();
    }

};
```

And you can do the same thing with MockB.

Comment: I think we are quite close here. What I like is that this construct is easily extended. Add classes C, D, E - no problem. Add MockWhatever - no effort. The only thing that bothers me is the initMock() method inside Base. This is code for testing inside a production class ...

Comment: @MacMannus But what I understand here is that the initialization code will not differ right ? If not you can still add in `MockA::initMock` after the call to `Base::initMock()` something like `x = 3;` if you want a different value for a particular child.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi If you don't want the initMock method in the base class, the only other solution I see to do it in the same way is to create another class like `class BaseMock` who contains the initMock method and everything else common to every Mock...

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Normally I try to avoid multiple inheritance whereever possible. But maybe this is not the normal case ;-)

Comment: It seems to me the initialization code is specific to the A/B derived classes, so they should have methods for initialization and your MockA should call A's initialization method which A normally calls. I'm with @TobiMcNamobi on the putting test code in production code is a huge no-no.

Comment: Of course the test code can not be in production code. So like I said sooner in the comments, to avoid duplicates in code create a Mock class as parent of MockA, etc... sounds reasonnable.

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud: if "Base" is the base class of A,B,C, there is no need to introduce multiple inheritance here (in this case MockA, MockB, MockC already inherit from Base). If "Base" is not the base class (but another class, lets call it `BaseABC`), your example won't work since then you cannot access members BaseABC.x, BaseABC.y, BaseABC.z directly within Base::initMock.

Comment: @DocBrown Yes but we said before that it would be better if there is no initMock in Base because base is a production class and the mocks are for test purpose.

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud: I wanted to point out to you that your current example (`Base` not beeing the base class the OP was talking of) does not work - it won't compile. You cannot access protected members of a different class from outside the inheritance hierarchy directly. See my own post for how to do it right.

Comment: That's right sorry, I didn't understand your point.

Answer (score 0):

If `Base` is the common base class of A, B, C holding protected members `Base::x`, `Base::y`, etc., then I guess there are accessor methods like

```
Base::SetX(type_x xval){x=_val;}
```

etc. So write a static function in a helper class `MockInit`

```
void MockInit::initForTests(Base &b)
{
    b.SetX(1);
    b.SetY("abc");
    b.SetZ(0.5);
}
```

and call that function this way:

```
MockA::init()
{
     MockInit::initForTests(*this);
}

MockB::init()
{
     MockInit::initForTests(*this);
}
```

That's it - simple and stupid. However, if there are no such accessor methods, and you have you have absolutely no access to x,y,z from outside the inheritance hierarchy, I would consider changing the initial design of `Base` for better testability. At least, I would consider to make `MockInit` a friend class of `Base`.

Comment: Unfortunately the protected members have getters only but no setters.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi: outside of your testing code, x,y,z must be initialized somehow, too. Why can't you use that mechanism for testing purposes, too?

Comment: A, B, C, and Base are legacy code. At the moment I don't want to change these classes because I'm writing unit tests for a class that just uses A, B, C. Now A, B, C are initialing themselves by accessing a database. Of course for unit testing this is not an option, so that's why I have the need for MockA, MockB, MockC.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi: legacy code for which you have the source code available, or legacy code only available as binary + headers? The first case gives you much more options, introducing a line like `friend class MockInit` into your common Base class is a low-risk change which enables much easier testing testing.